# Script for automatic proxy http traffic authorization

Tags: proxy

I have a virtual machine (local program) that works through a proxy, but does not support entering the login and password for the proxy. My proxy has a username and password. I need connect to the proxy from login and password so my virtual machine (local programm) from  the intermediate server receives ready-made authorized traffic. That is, I need an analogue of the router in the  local  port.
I found it, but iyt not work for me
https://github.com/sjitech/proxy-login-automator

Please tell me some solutions for me.